# Knockout: Click Binding with Foreach Parameters

Tags: google-maps, knockout.js

So, I have a Google Map with some locations. I'm trying to get the map markers to filter out when you click on the corresponding list item for it. The only way I can get it to work is if I put in the marker title's exact string like so:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: filteredItems()">
    <tr data-bind="click: toggleGroup('Michi Ramen')">
        <td id="listTitle" data-bind="text: $data.title"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Of course, that makes each list item filter the exact thing. Putting `toggleGroup.bind($data.title)` doesn't work.

This is my current viewModel:

```
var viewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.filters = ko.observableArray(data.filters);
    self.filter = ko.observable('');
    self.shops = data.shops;
    self.filteredItems = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
        var filter = self.filter().toLowerCase();
        if (!filter) {
            return self.shops();
        } else {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.shops(), function(Shop) {
                return Shop.title().toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1;
            });
        }
    }, viewModel);
};
```

And this is the function I'm using to try and filter the markers.

```
function toggleGroup(title) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var marker = markers[i];
        if (marker.title === title) {
            marker.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            markers[i].setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `marker.title === title` matches only if both strings have the same content.  You are looking for a substring matching.  This question could help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `title` is an `observable`, so you need to do `click: toggleGroup.bind($data, $data.title())`. 
Alternatively `click: function(data, event) { toggleGroup(data.title()) }`.